# Is there a way to make your computer automatically lock the screen?

Tags: password, security, lock

Just wanted a way to have my computer lock if I walk away from it it and forget to lock it manually.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Lock up how ? There's already screen savers for that.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 for mitch and want to know how to set a timer to make it lock for serg

Comment: In Unity, GNOME or which GUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `System Settings` there is a `Brightness & Lock` icon. This contains what you are looking for:

[image: lock]

This is on Gnome3, but should work similar on Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Search  system settings and click brightness and lock. Set the timer to dim the screen on x seconds of inactivity and the timer to lock after x seconds of dim screen.